# Why does changing/making errors in codebase sometimes destroy a session in Codeigniter/PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Why does changing/making errors in one's codebase sometimes destroy a session in Codeigniter/PHP? I can't figure out the logic of why this is happening sometimes and not others and its driving me nuts.

I'm wondering what the triggers are for calling sess_destroy(). Can a session only be destroyed if my script contains code that writes data to the session? I guess what i'm trying to figure out is whether there are redirect scripts baked into codeigniter/php to destroy a session upon parse errors even if I haven't explictly made calls to update the session data

thanks,

tim

Comment: Well, what changes did you make?

Comment: hi Damien, I'm not sure. When this has happened before I've made many changes so I've lost track of what may have destroyed the session. I asked this question with the hope that I might get a better understanding of the triggers to destroy a session. Can you please see my updated question above that this starting to dig a little deeper? thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make some change in your code that result in parse error or other type of fatal error then it's possible that php cannot write data to session - because script dies before the php calls session_write(), which php usually does automatically at the end of script.

So if php never gets a chance to call session_write() you session data is lost.

You should check your php error log to see if you have any fatal errors, find the source of them and fix your script.

Comment: hi Dmitri, thanks for your suggestion. So does this imply that the session can only be destroyed if my script contains code that writes data to the session? I guess what i'm trying to figure out is whether their are redirect scripts baked into codeigniter/php to destroy a session upon parse errors even if I haven't explictly made calls to update the session data.

Comment: You can manually call session_write_close() in your script. This is not a bad idea to call session_write_close() as soon as you know that no more updates to session data are coming. This way you can be sure that session data is saved, even if script dies after this line your session will be saved. See docs here http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: hmm, I'd like to preserve the user's ability to update some session data such as their name, picture `src=""`, etc. It seems silly to have to access the database every place I'd like to display the user's name, picture, etc. Wouldn't this limit the usefulness of `session_write_close()`?